# NGINX: HTTP redirect to HTTPS not working with node

Tags: http, redirect, nginx, https

I'm trying to redirect all HTTP reqs to HTTPS reqs. My backend is with node.
Here's my nginx config on ***conf.d/***:

```
upstream node {
server  127.0.0.1:8000;
}
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name mydomain.com;
    return 301  https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name mydomain.com;
    ssl on;
    gzip on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_session_timeout 5m;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://node;
    proxy_redirect off;
}
```

}

Here's my node config:

```
// Calls config file to ExpressJS instance 
var app = require('./config/express')();

// Calls config file to MongoDB
require('./config/database')('mongodb://10.0.2.18/mydb');

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){

console.log('HTTP listening on' + app.get('port'));

});
```

It's working when I explicitly use the HTTPS protocol. However if I use the HTTP protocol it does not work, ie, does not redirect to HTTPS.

Any suggestion?

Comment: For what it's worth, if anyone else sees this in the same situation as me: I just upgraded from an old version of Nginx to the latest in order to use HTTP2 and long story short, my HTTPS redirect wasn't working because I still had to kill the old Nginx process(es) and start Nginx again.

Answer (score 1):

I looked for a similar example and found this page: https://bjornjohansen.no/redirect-to-https-with-nginx

The only meaningful difference I see is that on that on that page he's doing `return 301 https://$host` instead of `$server_name`.  This question seems to indicate that it might be better to use host: https://serverfault.com/questions/706438/what-is-the-difference-between-nginx-variables-host-http-host-and-server-na

I'd also double check all the `server_name` entries in the config.

You should be able to see the redirect by using a tool like Charles, wireshark, or maybe even the browser debugger too - so it ought to be possible to work out what's being sent back using that.  It may also be in the logfile.

If it works properly when you go directly to `https://` that means that the https and the connection between nginx and node are working correctly; just need to get the redirect to work properly.

Comment: I just found the error. I left a rule on my iptables list that redirects packages from port 80 to 3000. This way the request would not even come to nginx. With the port 443 it was working because there was no rule for it.